# Tuning sqoop export performance

Tags: oracle, hadoop, export, performance-testing, sqoop

I'm exporting **2 Billion records** from hive to Oracle database using sqoop on AWS EMR. I have tried `--batch` and `--num-mappers` parameters which have already helped increase the performance.

Does tuning `-Dsqoop.export.statements.per.transaction` and `-Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement` helps?

Expecting suggestions on other tuning parameters for increasing export throughput.

Answer (score 1):

did you try including the `--direct` option? I have seen that this increase the performance in Oracle imports depending on your oracle version.

Comment: I have already tried that out, using it was little slower than without it. Does that need anything apart from Oracle jdbc driver?

Answer (score 1):

> Does tuning `-Dsqoop.export.statements.per.transaction` and
>   `-Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement` helps?

1. Yes. Refer to this link:
   https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/70258/sqoop-performance-tuning.html

   After some point, stop tweaking
   "`sqoop.export.records.per.statement`" (as you might encounter
   `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`) and start tweaking
   "`sqoop.export.statements.per.transaction`".
2. Export performance depends on the degree of parallelism, so increase
   the number of mappers and see how the performance scales up.

   Use partitioning as mentioned in
   https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_partitioning
   Though pretty old, an experience on the same is available in this link
   https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/sqoop-user/201406.mbox/%3CCFCDC24C.A85D%25brenden.cobb@humedica.com%3E
3. As in the previous answer, use direct mode by using "--direct"
   parameter

Try each approach and adopt the one that works for you.